# רבי vs תלמיד חכם

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

There is a point where one can choose between becoming a Rebbi (In this context rebbi refers to one that teaches students in school/Yeshiva) and learning all day looking to be a Talmud Chachum, Gadol Hador.
Having a Gadol Hador is incredibly important (in my opinion) but so is having great Rebbeim teaching the future generation.

Is it better for one to become a Rebbi (teacher) or try and learn all day and become a Gadol Hador for the nation? - Obviously doing both would be the best but that's not always/usually possible since to become a Gadol Hador one usually must learn all the time which would take away his time to be a teacher.

Note: Being a teacher means a full time teacher.

Comment: It takes more than just the ability to read and speak English to be a good English teacher. One cannot simply choose to be a good teacher. There is a false binary here.

Comment: You forgot farmer. Maybe everyone should spend their time learning to become the best possible farmer. Food is really important.

Comment: The two are not mutually exclusive; one can be involved in teaching children, but also progress steadily in one's learning. Certainly this is the case if one teaches at an advanced level as this forces him to prepare properly; מתלמידי יותר מכולם.

Comment: The focus of this question is quite vague. IMO, every male adult needs a parnassa (job / income) to support his family. This concept is supported by many adages mentioned throughout the Mishna and Talmud, and is also implied in the ketubah. So, if one is studying all day in the Bet Midrash and has no income whatsoever and is supported by the community (I know that many do this), I don't think this is the ideal situation, and I would recommend becoming a rebbe as a form of parnassa, if the person is qualified. Or, support the learning with some other profession.

Comment: No idea why this was closed. Simple question: is it better to ficus on one's own studies or to teach others. Questions of prioritizing mitzvot are typical in halachic literature.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39566/discussion-on-question-by-huddie96--vs--).